# Publishing mathematical puzzles in math stack exchange

Tags: discussion

If I want to publish a mathematical puzzle in math stack exchange, rather than a question, what can I do ?

Comment: Did you read [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1190/43351)?

Comment: There was an [area51 proposal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231/puzzling-area-51-proposal) for a separate site for puzzles. But it is now dead.

Comment: MSE is not a site meant for "publishing" anything, puzzles or otherwise.

Comment: Some completely different: Is this your account as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/79650/peter

Comment: We have the [tag:puzzle] tag, but my personal experience was, let's say, mixed...

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a puzzle question
[LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351333/442)

But a second attempt went nowhere.  Try one if you want, and see what happens.  Maybe follow the advise in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4233/442 and make it clear in the post what it is.